# Detection of Eye movement in sleep state using a thermal recorded video

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect the eye movement when it is closed in Far-infrared. I am able to detect the eye region in a thermal video. Once I cropped out the eye, to calculate the eye ball movement in closed eye is with the help of movement of eye lashes.

For this part I thought of finding the intensity value of each pixel and it's location then I will store these values as an array element i.e  A[(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2)......(xn,yn,zn)]. where x,y represent location and z represents pixel intensity value. Once i am able to make this cropped out part as an array representation. Then i can sort this array then divide this array according to the pixel intensity values.

These values consists of so many intensities but then i will be dividing this into two Arrays according to the occurrence of intensities.
1. The background as it has same intensity values.
2. The roi eye lashes.

when we get the 2nd array, I will store these (x,y,z) of the present frame then i repeat this procedure for the next  frame where i will be getting another 2nd array then i can check the difference between the (x,y) of two frames. If the difference is 0, it shows there is no eye movement but if it's not zero then we can say that there is a slight detectable change in eye movement.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

blur_radius = 1.0
threshold = 50
A = ()


video = cv2.VideoCapture('12.avi')
while True:
        ret, frame = video.read()
        frame = frame[:,1:600]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15,15), 0)
        (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
        image = frame
        (x,y) = maxLoc
        cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 15, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(maxLoc),(390,190),(0,255,0),2) 
        roi = frame [y:190,x:390]
        try:
                roi = cv2.resize(roi, None, fx=4, fy=4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                cv2.imshow("Eye",roi)
                cv2.imshow("Eyecorner", image)
        except:
                print''

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7XzN.jpg]
detected eye in a single frame

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iObmJ.jpg]
the cropped eye region from a thermal video

I am not sure whether it is the correct way to do. I am unable to figure out how to put the above explained as a code.Is it a feesible thing. sorry if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think you should state your question more clearly. From what I understand I would suggest to use image histogram to find background - you will notice large amount of similar samples, as you expect uniform background. Try keeping your arrays in following format A(x,y,t), where x,y is location and t is time. This will make movement detection easier to implement

Comment: given that you know the exact location of the eye in each point in time i will look at the difference in intensity between those frames. A movement will be the amount of pixels that has differences above some threshold. This is what is referred to has "change detection" and there is a lot of algorithms that solve this problem.